# Rewriting java if statements in clojure syntax

Tags: clojure

I have a set of recursive if statements written in Java and I tried taking it to clojure syntax but got the ArrayOutOfBound error. The functions accepts row = 0, col = 0 and a multidimensional array of characters.

This is the Java Code:

```
public static boolean solveMaze(int r, int c, char[][] maze) {

    //check for boundaries
    if(r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= maze.length || c >= maze[0].length)
        return false;
    //base case, did i reach the finish?
    if(maze[r][c] == '@')
        return true;
    //check if I'm at a valid point
    if(maze[r][c] != '-')
    //I have hit a wall, not a valid solution
        return false;
    //must be on a path, may be the right path
    //leave a bread crumb
    maze[r][c] = '!';
    //check above
    if(solveMaze(r-1,c, maze)) {

        maze[r][c] = '+';
        return true;
    }
    //check below
    if(solveMaze(r+1,c, maze)) {

        maze[r][c] = '+';
        return true;
    }
    //check left
    if(solveMaze(r,c-1, maze)) {

        maze[r][c] = '+';
        return true;
    }
    //check right
    if(solveMaze(r,c+1, maze)) {

        maze[r][c] = '+';
        return true;
    }
    //if I reach this point...
    return false;
}
```

This is my code in clojure that provides the Index out of bound error:

```
    (defn solveMaze [r c m]
    (def tt true)
    ;(def che false)

    ;check to verify boundaries
    (if (or (or (or (< r 0) (< c 0)) (>= r (count m))) (>= c (count (str (m 0)))))
        false
        true
    )
    ;Check to know if the @ symbol has been found
    (if (= (get-in m[r c]) "@")
        true
        false
    )
    ;Checking if current index is a valid one
    (if (not= (get-in m[r c]) "-")
        ;Wall hit
        false
        true
    )
    ;found a path, leave a breadcrumb
    (def temp_map (assoc-in m[r c] "!"))
    ;Check North
    (if (= (solveMaze (dec r) c m) true)
        (def temp_map (assoc-in m [r c] "+"))
        true   
        ;false
    )
    ;Check South
    (if (= (solveMaze (inc r) c m) true)
        (def temp_map (assoc-in m[r c] "+"))
        true
        ;false
    )
    ;Check East
    (if (= (solveMaze r (dec c) m) true)
        (def temp_map (assoc-in m[r c] "+"))
        true
        ;false
    )
    ;Check West
    (if (= (solveMaze r (inc c) m) true)
        (def temp_map (assoc-in m[r c] "+"))
        true
        ;false
    )
    ;If code gets here
    (= tt false)
```

)

Please is there something I am doing wrongly??? I have tried several if constructs using clojure but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can not translate a java program verbatim into clojure in many cases.  `if` does not return on it's own but everything returns the result of the last statement.  So at least you have to cascade your if-statements.  Also never `def`  other than top-level.  Use `let`

Comment: Hi cfrick, thanks for the comment, does that mean that I cannot get the same construct in clojure?

Comment: @FoskieBlue yes and no. That you need, is to read some basics of clojure, since what are you doing is counteridiomatic (as for `def`s inside the function) and wrong (as for the rest). The clojure way to do something like this is `cond` https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond

Comment: The body of a Clojure function is a series of expressions. These are evaluated in sequence. The value of the last is returned. The values of any previous expressions are discarded. Hence your checks that `r` and `c` are within bounds are performed, but the `false` results are discarded, and evaluation proceeds regardless of the validity of the `r` and `c` values. I was going to show you idiomatic Clojure for this, interesting since it's so different, that would lead you down the path of righteousness. But now that the question is closed, I can only point out your immediate error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on the basics of Clojure:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/) (online & book)
- [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure) book
- [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) book

Comment: Any of them in fact, first chapters would be enough

Comment: This is *accurate*, but I'm not sure that it's *a good-faith effort to answer the question*. Probably better to vote-to-close the question as too broad to be answerable (as is generally the case for most "please translate this code for me" questions that don't narrow down a single, specific, narrow statement with the smallest possible amount of surrounding infrastructure to make it runnable/testable).

Answer (score 0):

Use a cond to solve this instead of if. The way the code executes now is that first if is evaluated and then it goes to the next line to execute rest of code. With cond, if an expression is evaluated to be true, it returns the value and won't evaluate other expressions.

Refer :https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond