# Recursive function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have written a recursive function in java and want to implement the same for Clojure.

The java code snippet is below.

```
private boolean solve(int i, int j) {
    // some other code
    if ((solve(i - 1, j)) == true) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((solve(i, j + 1)) == true) {
        return true;
    }
    // some code!!!!
    return false;
}
```

How can this be implemented in Clojure?

Comment: We'd need to see the actual function, this is just a rough sketch.

Comment: Please see the resources here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353990/rewriting-java-if-statements-in-clojure-syntax/56361177

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? All except the "some code" part can be achieved using `cond`.

Comment: If you decide to revise your question, consider that your function as currently structured isn't tail recursion friendly and won't work with the `recur` form.  This could potentially leave you open to blowing the call stack.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Better yet, use `or`.

Comment: @amalloy I was going for a more generalized suggestion for an if/else tree. In this case though, ya, `or` might as well be used to join the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

an almost direct equivalent is

```
(defn solve [i j]
  (or ;; some other code
      (solve (dec i) j)
      (solve i (inc j))
      ;; some code
      ))
```

Notice the absence of a `return` statement - everything is an expression.

In your java snippet "some other code" must have the ability to return truthy, otherwise you end up with a stack overflow (in place of "endless recursion").

The reason the code can be so short is that the `or` macro short-circuits evaluation (ie. it stops evaluation as soon as a meaningful result can be deduced).

In the clojure example "some other code" must be an expression that could evaluate to false or nil.

If you need to "return `false` immediately" from "some other code" your expression needs to be a bit more convoluted.

Comment: I think you mean it must have the ability to return `true` in JS, and in Clojure must be able to evaluate to something truthy, no? Having the header able to return false doesn't help you get to a base case, if you use it within an `or`.

Comment: @amalloy you are right, I was a bit to quick to answer. I have edited to reflect your comment